# Код завершения программы

Tags: bash

Мне нужно написать скрипт, при выполнении которого пингуется IP адрес, при этом, если пинг не проходит, то ошибка записывается в лог-файл. В обратном случае ничего не происходит.

Все бы ничего, пока я не столкнулас к кодом ответа команды. Если ping проходит успешно, то ответ - `0`, если нет - `-1`. Это все понятно, но как записать в условии if то, что код не равен `0` и я хочу вывод статистики в файл, как он обозначается этот код ответа?

Я себе это представляю где-то так:

```
#!/bin/bash 

ping -c 5 10.181.85.16
if [код ответа -ne 0]; then >error
else
exit
fi
```

я отправляю 5 пакетов, если пинг не проходит, то записываю ошибку в файл `error`, в обратном случае - "выход". К сожалению, это все, к чему я пришла.

Comment: http://eddnet.org/?p=836 это похоже на то, что вам нужно

Comment: http://linuxforum.ru/post/307096

Comment: [ $? -ne 0 ]&& >>error

Comment: небольшой список литературы имеется в описании метки [bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)

Comment: Спасибо! Обязятельно прочитаю.

Comment: `мне бы хотелось установить выполнение скрипта каждые, скажем, 30 минут` - почитайте про утилиту cron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

код возврата последней выполненной команды содержится в специальной переменной `$?`.

---

из [документации](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html):

> ?
>       ($?) Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

---

в приложении к вашему коду:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo $? >> error
```

обратите внимание на то, что выражение внутри квадратных скобок должно быть отделено от скобок пробелами.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Так как `if` как раз и проверяет код возврата на равенство нулю (а с отрицанием - `!` - на неравенство), идеологически более правильно не использовать `$?`, а писать команду прямо в `if`:

```
if ! ping -c 5 10.181.85.16; then
    ... # error
else
    ... # no error
fi
```

Можно использовать более короткую форму, без `if`, если вам нужна только одна ветка условия:

```
ping -c 5 10.181.85.16 || echo > error
```